# How to zoom in-out a pie chart using core-plot?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, core-plot, xcode4.2, zooming

How to zoom in and out a pie chart in iPhone using core-plot? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `pieRadius` to change the size of the pie.

Comment: Thanks, How should i change the pie radius by touching pie chart ? what event should be used to calculate pie radius ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
-(void)pieChart:(CPTPieChart *)plot sliceWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index{
  plot.pieRadius+=10;
}
```